# Additional comma in jsp data confusing split in java

Tags: ajax, jsp, concatenation, numberformatexception

I am getting xml data from ajax call in jsp

```
<details>
<std><name>Dr. Watson</name><age>40</age></std>
**<std><name>Dr, Strange</name><age>55</age></std>**
</details>
```

Parsing the data in js function
and concatenating data from child nodes with comma as delimiter
Dr. Watson,40
and assigning this value to select option using
**new Option("text", concatenatedString)**
After submitting the page selected option (multiple select allowed) value is again splitted in java with comma.
**Issue arises when there is comma in data obtained from ajax call in any of the nodes** 
Dr, Strange,55
Increasing number of comma and leading to number format exception: type mismatch due to index.

---

1. To keep changes to minimum, Is it safe to replace comma in ajax data
   with **&#44** and replace again in java with comma to avoid the
   issue or any other way to handle?
2. Or Can we bind an array with
   select option value tag using new Option("text", array) and get
   value of array in java using its index?

Comment: Hi, you need to do this using ajax? Also , can you elaborate more ?